# What does it mean to “grow organically”?

Tags: meaning

I understand what the term as it's applied to Biotechnology, Chemistry. I am not quite sure what it means when it's applied to other area.

One example is:

> Or do you allow the specifications to grow organically by allowing all of the developers to write their own tests, and forget about having a Software Architect?

which is taken from [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21291/what-is-the-role-of-a-software-architect-in-the-test-driven-development-process) SE Post.

Does it mean to grow dynamically with changed requirements or get modified with changed requirements?

Comment: No pesticides may be used on those specifications.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this context, for the specifications to *grow organically* means there is no overarching control or direction. Each developer writes their own tests, without consultation with or approval of a higher authority. Metaphorically, it evokes an image of a tree or plant which grows outward and higher from the bottom up. So the phrase describes a "bottom up" process, as opposed to a "top down" architectural or dictatorial process.

So you see, your final question "Does it mean to grow dynamically with changed requirements or get modified with changed requirements?" isn't really addressed by the phrase. It simply means there is no single authority which dictates the specifications. They will arise (grow organically) from each developer's tests.

Comment: Lack of overarching control isn't necessarily the fundamental principle at work here. A tree grows into a tree because it is controlled by its DNA. Just as a tree grows a series of branches governed by its DNA, so does a software program grow branches outward governed by a fundamental set of specifications. More info here: http://findarticles.com/p/articles/mi_m0SMG/is_n5_v10/ai_8411932/

Comment: @Robert: Perhaps inserting "perceived" would help? "Lack of perceived overarching control." If we are willing to discuss DNA with regards to a tree's organic growth than it would probably be difficult to say _anything_ does not have some form of overarching control.

Comment: @MrHen: It is more a question of distributed control, as opposed to a rigid, hierarchical command and control structure. Computing history is replete with examples of large, monolitic, centrally controlled software projects that collapsed under their own weight, which is why we use [agile software development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) methods now, for the most part.

Comment: @Robert: Ah, excellent point. I think that makes much more sense.

Comment: @Robert Exactly, that's what I was driving at. Organic growth is distributed growth **not** top-down directed growth.

Comment: Ah, I see. Guess I was focusing on your phrase, "no authority with final say over the specifications." There is always such an authority.

Comment: Oh yes, good point. Just because the growth isn't directed, doesn't mean it can't be "pruned." ;-) I should remove that phrase to avoid confusion. I hope my edit agrees with your intentions.

Answer (score 7):

I see a slightly different meaning than ghoppe here, which is more about steady, sustained, fixed-rate growth. The *New Oxford American Dictionary* somewhat supports this:

> **organic:** characterized by continuous or natural development: *companies expand as much by acquisition as by organic growth*.

Comment: +1: Interesting.  If I understand this correctly, does it mean that organic growth means hiring individuals and promoting from within rather than buying a smaller, existing company and assimilating those employees?

Comment: @oosterwal: yes, I would say so

Comment: I agree, but I think in the context of the source there was a contrast of what was driving the growth rather than what rate of growth or type of growth was occurring.

Comment: I think that in this definition, organic growth for a company means especially growing its sales volume and profits by selling more products, serving more customers, being active in more markets, without emphasis on hiring individuals.

Answer (score 1):

Here, for the specs to *grow organically* implies that they emerge over time via implicit consensus, rather than being manufactured or prescribed beforehand. Often, this implies a grassroots structure rather than being indoctrinated by an external agent (e.g. the software architect).